# syntax error in my SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have a syntax error in my SQL queries,what's wrong?

*this is the query:*

```
    CREATE TABLE post_cat(
    cat_id int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT null PRIMARY key,
    cat_text varchar(255),
    post_cat varchar,
    FOREIGN KEY (post_cat) REFERENCES post(post_cat)
    )
```

Comment: What is  your error?

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table `telegram`.`post_cat` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: Add your query for adding the `post` table which hold the `post_cat` before this query.

Answer (score 3):

All varchars need a length specification.

```
CREATE TABLE post_cat(
cat_id int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT null PRIMARY key,
cat_text varchar(255),
post_cat varchar(1000),
FOREIGN KEY (post_cat) REFERENCES post(post_cat)
);
```

Comment: now I have new error

MySQL said: Documentation

#1005 - Can't create table `telegram`.`post_cat` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Answer (score 2):

You need a length for the `varchar`:

```
CREATE TABLE post_cat (
    cat_id int(2) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT null PRIMARY key,
    cat_text varchar(255),
    post_cat varchar(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (post_cat) REFERENCES post(post_cat)
);
```

The length should match the definition in the `post` table.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a777a) is a SQL Fiddle showing the table creation.

Comment: now I have new error

MySQL said: Documentation

#1005 - Can't create table `telegram`.`post_cat` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: `post_cat` seems like a really strange primary key for a table called `post`.  Nevertheless, the code works with the correct column definitions, as shown in the SQL Fiddle.